# Display annotation text of plot simultaneously in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, annotations, mplcursors

I am trying to display annotation text for multiple plots in the same graph(or figure) simultaneously. The below code works perfectly but it displays one annotation for one plot at a time, but my graph has multiple plots. plot1_list, plot2_list, plot3_list are the lists of plots in my graph. The annotation texts are in the form of "labels" in my plots.
How can i display the annotation texts for every plots in each list simultaneously?

```
import mplcursors



cursor1 = mplcursors.cursor(plot1_list, hover=False, bindings={"toggle_visible": "h", "toggle_enabled": "e"})
@cursor1.connect("add")
def on_add(sel):
    sel.annotation.set_text(sel.artist.get_label())

cursor2 = mplcursors.cursor(plot2_list, hover=False, bindings={"toggle_visible": "h", "toggle_enabled": "e"})
@cursor2.connect("add")
def on_add(sel):
    sel.annotation.set_text(sel.artist.get_label())

cursor3 = mplcursors.cursor(plot3_list, hover=False, bindings={"toggle_visible": "h", "toggle_enabled": "e"})
@cursor3.connect("add")
def on_add(sel):
    sel.annotation.set_text(sel.artist.get_label())
```

plot list in above code are created using below code:

```
label1 = str("MAXIMUM HEAD=" + str(m_head))
label2 = str("MAXIMUM POWER=" + str(m_power))
label3 = str("MAXIMUM EFFICIENCY=" + str(m_efficiency))

plot1, = host.plot(y0, y, linestyle=styles[0], color=colorstouse[count], label=label1)
plot2, = par1.plot(y0, y1, linestyle=styles[1], color=colorstouse[count], label=label2)
plot3, = par2.plot(y0, y2, linestyle=styles[2], color=colorstouse[count], label=label3)
```

[image: Attached is the image of a sample plot]

Comment: host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)

    plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

    par1 = host.twinx()
    par2 = host.twinx()

    new_fixed_axis = par1.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
    par1.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right", axes=par1, offset=(0, 0))

    par1.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)


    new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
    par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right", axes=par2, offset=(60, 0))

    par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)

Comment: It has same x-axis but different y-axis.

Comment: I have added an image of plot. If you will notice one of the plot has an annotation on clicking but as soon as i click the other plot, the annotation appears on the other and the current one disappears. I want annotation on both of them blue and red plot.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do have the latest version. In my case too all three annotations appear for max head, max power and max efficiency. But the issue is they only appear for EACH COLOR OF PLOT. I mean lets say in above image, i need total 6 annotations, but it doesnt work. It only shows three.

Comment: Actually my plots are dynamically. It depends on User selection. It can be 6 it can be 90. How should i approach in that case?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you would need a separate mplcursor for each curve. That way each of them can be individually turned on or off.

The code looks a bit more complicated than necessary. Here is an attempt to simplify. The example shows 15 curves using 3 axes. Note that it can become very crowded, so 90 curves might be a bit too much.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mplcursors

num_devices = 5
fig, host = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()
par2.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.1))

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
y = -x ** 2 + 5 * x + 10
y1 = 10 + 20 * np.cos(x)
y2 = 30 + 5 * np.sin(x)

ys = [y + np.random.uniform(10, 30) for i in range(num_devices)]
y1s = [y1 + np.random.uniform(10, 30) for i in range(num_devices)]
y2s = [y2 + np.random.uniform(10, 30) for i in range(num_devices)]

colors = plt.cm.tab10.colors
plots = []
for dev in range(num_devices):
    plot1 = host.plot(x, ys[dev], c=colors[dev], ls='-', label=f'plot 1 - dev {dev}')
    plot2, = par1.plot(x, y1s[dev], c=colors[dev], ls='--', label=f'plot 2 - dev {dev}')
    plot3, = par2.plot(x, y2s[dev], c=colors[dev], ls=':', label=f'plot 3 - dev {dev}')
    plots += [plot1, plot2, plot3]

print(plots)
for i, plot in enumerate(plots):
    cursor = mplcursors.cursor(plot, hover=False, bindings={"toggle_visible": "h", "toggle_enabled": "e"})
    cursor.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(sel.artist.get_label()))
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]